# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to use `vue-router` to display routed components below my navbar component but I get an error specified in the title.

Here is my code:

#### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import app from './app';


Vue.use(VueRouter);


const foo = {
  template: '<div>foo</div>',
};

const bar = {
  template: '<div>bar</div>',
};

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: foo,
  },
  {
    path: '/bar',
    component: bar,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(app),
});
```

#### app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fs-navbar/>
    <main>
      <router-view/>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>

<script>
import fsNavbar from './components/fs-navbar';

export default {
  components: {
    fsNavbar,
  },
};
</script>
```

#### components/fs-navbar.vue

```
<template>
  <nav>...</nav>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.component('fs-navbar', {
  // logic
});
</script>
```

This app causes an error:

```
vue.js?3de6:2574[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in component <fs-navbar>)
```

If I add `fs-navbar` template directly into `app.vue`'s template everything is working as intended. Without router app is working as well.

I'm using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) with [this template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)(vuejs2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that `Vue.component()` return value isn't working with the router.

When changed:

```
export default Vue.component('component-name', {})
```

to:

```
export default {}
```

Everything is working fine.

Comment: @doug65536 Oh, that is just shortcut for any component properties. I will edit this to not confuse people with spread syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Smilar problem, when I write:

```
let routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: require('./components/member.vue')
}]
```

it failed:[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

**add ".default", it works!**

```
let routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: require('./components/member.vue').default
}]
```

PS:"vue": "^2.5.2","vue-router": "^3.0.1""vue-loader": "^13.3.0",

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v13.0.0